# Whats the best way to convert an integer to a string in the context of making a "Loot" simulator?

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner in Javascript so please bare with me. What I have setup so far is a simple 6 sided dice. My goal is to assign each "side" to a number so that for instance if I roll a '6' , the 6 will print and have a value of "Dharoks Platebody".

```
    document.querySelector('#roll').addEventListener('click', roll)
    
    let num = 6
    
    function roll() {
    let diceRoll = Math.floor( Math.random() * 6 + 1)
    
    num.toString('Dharoks Platebody')
    alert(num)
    }
```

This is what I have so far but it returns the error "radix argument must be between 2 and 36" .
Now obviously I could and likely will research that particular error more but my real question here is what is the most efficient way to go about this?

Comment: `num.toString('Dharoks Platebody')` seems to be completely on the wrong track. I assume you want some kind of `Map` from numbers to strings instead?

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array):

```js
const values = [
    "value if 1",
    "value if 2",
    "value if 3",
    "value if 4",
    "value if 5",
    "value if 6",
];

const num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

alert(num);

alert(values[num - 1]);
```

There is a `- 1` there because array indices start counting from 0. So the first item in the array would be the "0th position", and so on.

Comment: After reading up on arrays I realized this is perfect and more so what I was going for than .map. I really appreciate the response.